# Can the policy of a nation have influence in this situation?

Tags: probability

In a nation (with large population) it is forbidden to have more than one child unless the first child is a girl. In that case a second child is allowed, but there it stops: no more than two childs are allowed. People are eager to get a boy, so normally if the first child is a girl they go for a second. If a child is picked at random in that country then what is the probability that it is a boy?

Note: no abortions are allowed.

Comment: Are you assuming that a family that have had a girl as first child automatically have a second child?

Comment: @mfl  Yes, thank you. I have repaired that.

Comment: How many couples are there in the country?

Comment: @Tharindu Billions.

Comment: @Vera That sounds like planet earth to me, not just a country ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Under reasonable (though maybe not exactly correct) assumptions the probability is 50%, basta. Among these assumptions are

- The general probability of a boy or girl birth is 50%.
- There is no such thing as a father who produces more X or more Y sperms than average
- Subsequent births are independant events (at least regarding the sex of the child)
- Twin births are ignored

While these look reasonable, it might be reasonable that they are wrong, e.g. a first-born girl might cause homones or other mechanisms to alter the distributions of the second birth (however, I am unaware of such an effect). At least the first seems assumption, howevre, is observably wrong, check the statistics!

---

Think of it this way: You have a fair coin that is thrown very often. If you pick a random toss out of the many tosses you do, what is the probability of heads?
Now chang ethe experiment: Instead of you tossing the coin yourself, every couple in the ocuntry is lining up in a long queue and each couple is allowed to toss the coin once. Those who get tails are allowed to re-enter the queue. This does not change the fact that the coin is thrown a lot of times, no different from the first experiment.

Comment: My intuition agrees with you. However, suppose you pick a family first and
after that the child (or one of the children) of this family. The chance
that it is a family with one boy is $0.5$ and in that case it is
for sure that a boy is picked. This gives feed to the thought: there
will be a chance of $0.5\times1+0.5\times0.5$ on a boy. What is the
mistake in this thinking?

Comment: @Vera There is a difference between picking a random child on the on hand and on the other hand picking a random couple and then a random child of theirs. In fact the latter may fail completely as having a child is not compulsary. (I read "pick a foo at random" as "pick a foo at random according to uniform distribution")

Comment: You could 'pick a child' by 'picking a family' out of all families that have children and secondly 'picking (one of) the child(ren) of this family'. But I think I see some light: if there were $4$ families and this 'composed' on the *expected* way then you would have the families: $B$, $B$, $GB$, and $GG$. Then $3$ of the $6$ are boys wich agrees with your answer.